# Weird C++ syntax that Visual C++ 2022 understands but C++Builder rejects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder

I'm updating a huge legacy system, and am currently stumped by the following function:

```
template <class EL>
EL& FastInsertVector<EL>::operator[](size_type index)
{
    return (EL&) FastInsertVectorBase::operator [][](index);
}
```

MS VC++ 2022 compiles it happily, whereas C++ Builder 11.1.5 rejects it saying:

> expected expression

If I remove the second set of `[]`, both compilers are happy. Unfortunately, this is shared code that both compilers must be able to handle.

This codebase is huge, and has no tests, and I'm having difficulty actually understanding what this syntax even means.

Is this valid C++ syntax? Can anyone explain what it's trying to express?

Comment: It's possible that I've been out of town for a while, but I'm pretty sure that there is no `operator[][]` in C++, and there never was. It's necessary to figure out what that abomination was actually accomplishing, and then reimplement it in standard C++. Perhaps hunt down the definition of `FastInsertVectorBase`, and look at what it's defining.

Comment: please show a [mcve]

Comment: If you can make both compilers happy, why is this a problem? Not even in C++23 adding the possibility of passing more than 1 operand inside `[]` afaik allows for this syntax. assuming the intention here is to invoke the version `operator[]` implemented in the ancestor `FastInsertVectorBase`, `FastInsertVectorBase::operator[](index)` is indeed the correct syntax according to the standard... Btw: have you actually used this function in MSVC. MSVC may be a bit sloppy with syntax checks for non-specialized templates.

Comment: MS compiler is known to ignore nonsense or non-valuable expressions while they are ill-formed, because their over-use of regular expressions to analyze code.. And template methods that weren't instantiated and used  aren't checked at all, so likely this operator isn't used anywhere.

Comment: Thanks all. As far as I can tell, it supposed to be an 'improved', faster, version of stl::vector. It was written in 2002 and my intention now is to replace it with stl:vector as it's not even used in a place where speed matters. Swift - you were right, this weird code isn't even used so I've removed it from the code base... I'm kind of glad it wasn't me failing to understand it!

Comment: *"Can anyone explain what it's trying to express?"* -- since it is non-standard syntax, this would be a question for someone who can make inferences based on how it is used -- that is, a question for you. (And the one-word answer, "no", to your first question is not long enough for a StackOverflow answer.)

Comment: Judging from the code snippet, it attempts to call the base class's `operator[]` and cast whatever it returns to `EL`. I.e. it wants to do `return (EL&) FastInsertVectorBase::operator[](index);`. The double `[][]` is pretty certainly not valid syntax. However, MSVC does not complain about it as long as the function does not get instantiated (i.e. called), compare [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3hP4WMc7c). So my guess is that the shown `FastInsertVector<EL>::operator[]` is actually unused in the code and could be removed entirely.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie who tells you that MSVC uses regular expression to parse code? That would be extremely silly. They even captured the whole token stream instead of doing 2-pass parsing when it comes to templates which isn't standard comformant so now they've switched to the standardized template parsing method

Comment: Surely it is a typo and supposed to just be the single pair of `[]`

Comment: @Sedenion you can use the [`/permissive-` option](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/) to get the standard behavior and [MSVC will report an error](https://godbolt.org/z/nTxrv4EY7)

Comment: @phuclv Not in this case because it's likely was case when method wasn't used, a quirk shared will their compilers since VC4. Yet since Vc6 their parser fails randomly on totally silly stuff, especially with nested loops with reuse of identifiers or CRTP and allowed non-conformant use of typenames in some case (which became standard now). It's as if there is some leftovers of classical lexxer algorithm, or their parser is hand-written for every case. It might not regex directly but manually pre-built lexical trees.